# Logistic Regression keep crashing the kaggle notebook

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am using Logistic Regression to train my model. My dataset has 1.6 million rows. After train_test_split and feature selection (it contains 18 features originally), when I run Logistic Regression, it keeps running out of memory and crashes the notebook. It was working fine a few days ago and now it has been more than 3 days and the problem still persists because of which I am not able to complete my project.

This is what I did, after train test split

```
X_train_movies=[]
X_test_movies=[]
for row in range(0,len(X_train.index)):
  X_train_movies.append(' '.join(str(x) for x in X.iloc[row,:]))

for row in range(0,len(X_test.index)):
  X_test_movies.append(' '.join(str(x) for x in X.iloc[row,:]))

tf=TfidfVectorizer()
X_train_enc=tf.fit_transform(X_train_movies)
X_test_enc=tf.transform(X_test_movies)

lb=LabelEncoder()
y_train_enc=lb.fit_transform(y_train)
y_test_enc=lb.fit_transform(y_test)

fs=SelectKBest(score_func=chi2,k=110)
fs.fit(X_train_enc,y_train_enc)

X_train_fs = fs.transform(X_train_enc)
X_test_fs = fs.transform(X_test_enc)

classifier= LogisticRegression()  
classifier.fit(X_train_fs, y_train_enc)
```

What should I do to prevent this from crashing?

Comment: The SelectKBest method you're using for feature selection can be memory-intensive if the input data is large. Have you tried reducing the number of selected features (k value) .